# Trying to return an object and display its properties

Tags: javascript

1. I am getting some data from spotify api.
2. Creating an object and saving some values from the returned JSON data
3. return the object
   4.. trying to display the object data.

   ```
   /* API ROUTES */
   router.get('/', (req, res) => { 
      // Get artist
      const data = getArtist('Drake');
      if(data) {
       console.log(data.id);
      } else {
        console.log('nothing in data');
      }


   });

   // Get an artist name
   function getArtist(name) {


    spotify
     .search({ type: 'artist', query: name })
     .then(function(response) {

       // Gets Name and Id of the artist
       const data = {
         "id": response.artists.items[1].id,
         "name":  response.artists.items[1].name
       }

       return data;
     })
     .catch(function(err) {
       console.log(err);
     });
   }
   ```

> Displays the error: nothing in data.

Coming from JAVA not sure what I am doing wrong in Javascript. Ideas? Is there a better way?

Comment: Spotify.search is an async call. By the time the call returns successfully, your code has already evaluated `data` which will always be `undefined`. You can observe the `data` property or execute your code in the success callback.

Comment: Thank you! I get it now @AmmoPT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try This:   

    router.get('/', (req, res) => { 
       // Get artist
       getArtist('Drake').then( (response) => {
         if(response) {
            const data = {
               "id": response.artists.items[1].id,
               "name":  response.artists.items[1].name
            }
            console.log(data.id);
         } else {
             console.log('nothing in data');
         }
       });
   });  

    // Get an artist name
    function getArtist(name) {
        return spotify.search({ type: 'artist', query: name });
    }
```